# Android - Remove all chips from chipgroup

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-chips

How do I remove all chips from a ChipGroup?

I know I can remove one chip by passing it to the `removeView` method or one chip by it's index by calling the `removeViewAt` and passing it's index, but I wanted to remove all views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all chips by calling the `removeAllViews` method:

```kotlin
val chipGroup = findViewById<ChipGroup>(R.id.chip_group)
chipGroup.removeAllViews()
```